# Can't see Top Navigation Bar on Root View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode6, navigationbar

I am trying to build a Universal iOS APP. I just started with root view controller and trying to display Navigation Bar on top.

Navigation Bar is visible on Xcode 6 preview mode, along with title that I added, but no matter what I do, it's not visible on the simulator.

**How can I show the navigation bar on simulator?**

Am using XCOde 6 & iOS 8. Forgot to mention that I am not using Navigation Controller & instead, am using the first view controller as the root view controller.

Actually, I don't want to use Navigation Controller as the root view controller, because it then takes control on all the pages, which I don't want. What if I want to change the back button the way i like, can I do that with Navigation Controller as root view controller?

Comment: Have you created UINavigationController as rootViewController??

Comment: in your storyboard take navigationViewController and give its root viewController.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a similar situation:

[image]

Check that your navigation controller is set as **initial view controller** and **visibile**: just click on your navigation controller and on your right:

[image]